# Spark Streaming. Issues with Py4j: Error while obtaining a new communication channel

Tags: python-2.7, streaming, real-time, py4j, apache-spark-1.3

I am currently running a real time Spark Streaming job on a cluster with 50 nodes on Spark 1.3 and Python 2.7. The Spark streaming context reads from a directory in HDFS with a batch interval of 180 seconds. Below are the configuration for the Spark Job:

> **spark-submit --master yarn-client --executor-cores 5 --num-executors 10 --driver-memory 10g --conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=2048 --conf spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead=2048 --conf spark.network.timeout=300 --executor-memory 10g**

The job runs fine for the most part. However, it throws a Py4j Exception after around 15 hours citing it **cannot obtain a communication channel**.

I tried reducing the Batch Interval size but then it creates an issue where the Processing time is greater than the Batch Interval.

Below is the Screenshot of the Error

[Py4jError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bJ65.jpg)

I did some research and found that it might be an issue with Socket descriptor leakage from here [SPARK-12617](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-12617)

However, I am not able to work around the error and resolve it. Is there a way to manually close the open connections which might be preventing to provide ports. Or do I Have to make any specific changes in the code to resolve this.

TIA

Comment: Found any fix for it?

Comment: @vkb Got a patch from cloudera to resolve the issue.